# Grouping operators in Spotify advanced search

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to use the Spotify web API to return multiple specific results in one response.

For example, maybe I want Spotify's detailed information for "Thriller", by Michael Jackson, and "Highway Star", by Deep Purple.

Since I don't already have the Spotify uris I need to use the Search method. And there's a page describing Spotify's advanced search syntax [here](http://www.spotify.com/us/about/features/advanced-search-syntax/). They support searching against specific fields, like track, artist, and album. They also support the basic boolean operators.

But there's nothing on that page (or anywhere else on the internet, as far as I can tell) describing how the boolean operator precedence works, or how you might go about grouping your search criteria.

I would need something effectively the same as (track:Thriller AND artist:"Michael Jackson") OR (track:"highway star" AND artist:"Deep Purple").

Using similar criteria to pull in just one track at a time works:

[http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=track:"thriller"+AND+artist:"michael+jackson"](http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=track%3a%22thriller%22+AND+artist%3a%22michael+jackson%22)

I tried to jump right in with the parentheses, even though they're not mentioned in the docs. No luck:

ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=(track:"thriller"+AND+artist:"michael+jackson")+OR+(track:"highway+star"+AND+artist:"deep+purple")

Then I thought I'd try playing with precedence. Maybe they don't just process left-to-right - maybe the ORs are all resolved, and then the ANDs:

ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=track:"thriller"+OR+track:"highway+star"+AND+artist:"michael+jackson"+OR+artist:"deep+purple"

That seemed promising, and returned 185 results, but it's not quite right. I'm seeing tracks named "Highway Star" from other bands. That seems to rule out "left-to-right", "OR-before-AND" AND "AND-before-OR". Which doesn't make any sense - what else is left?

Can anyone with more Spotify experience shed some light on how a query like this should work?

Comment: This question has been here for a while, and I also asked it on the Spotify IRC channel with no response. Do Spotify staff not monitor this site? They act like it's their official support method. Not trying to be pushy, I just find it hard to believe someone from Spotify would not know the behavior when multiple booleans are strung together. Even if no one on the dev team knows, it should only take a quick glance at the relevant code...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's not really much support for this in Spotify's Web API (I've tried myself, with the same outcome as you've had). And from the looks of it, the API's been worked on for a couple of years, so I wouldn't expect much to change.

However, I strongly recommend that you have a look at **[the Echo Nest API's](http://developer.echonest.com/)** instead; they support quite [powerful queries](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4) and have a bunch of awesome stuff in their API. 
Furthermore, they've also got support for [getting Spotify URI:s](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4#project-rosetta-stone) for the search results (tracks, artists etc). This means that you could probably stick to the EN API altogether.

Also, **The Echo Nest** are continuously adding more features to their API, so it's really become the go-to API for music (outperforming Last.fm and similar by far).

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with Echo Nest but that wasn't a possible solution this time around. We were working with another data provider, similar to Echo Nest (but which should probably remain nameless) which doesn't return Spotify URIs for its results. But the client wanted "play in Spotify" links.

Comment: The options were:  

- Make a separate Spotify call for each track (title+artist+album)  
- Make one complex Spotify call to cover all the tracks at once  
- Use some other service (like Echo Nest)  
  
The first option isn't viable because it would hammer the Spotify servers and definitely run into the rate limit. The last wasn't an option because the client specifically wanted to avoid pulling in more APIs (particularly Echo Nest's) for reasons I won't get into.

Comment: We ended up scrapping that project, partially because of the complete lack of support/response from Spotify. Which I find extremely frustrating. Obviously, stringing a bunch of ANDs and ORs together in a search does SOMETHING. We just need someone at Spotify familiar with the actual code to tell us what. I understand that the API is provided for free, but to get zero response from every support channel they list on their site is maddening. A simple "we don't know off the top of our heads and don't feel like taking ten minutes to figure it out, so you're out of luck" would be an improvement.